# iOS notifications don't work in production like in Test

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have a problem with `push notifications` in **development\distribution** (app that talk with production server).
We have the same certificate in `test` and in `productions` servers.
When I run my app on device that talk with the test `DB` (I save device token by email) I'm getting notification, but when the app talk with the production server, I never get notification...

- the certificate file is same on both servers
- I signing the app in the same way

What can be the problem?

Comment: Is your production server still talking to the sandbox sever at Apple or is it using Apple's production server?

Comment: You should have separate certificates for test and production.  Does your certificate say "Type: APNS Development iOS" like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/o9xrllrafd4tb2h/Screenshot%202014-09-17%2013.49.01.png?dl=0

Comment: I have 2 certificates with the same name, one is type: `APNs Development iOS` the second: `APNs Production iOS`

Comment: @Paulw11 do you mean what kind of `.p12` file I have on those servers?

Comment: No, I mean are you talking to the two different endpoints at Apple as you said you had the same certificate, but you need a different certificate for the production environment as @ChrisTruman said.

Comment: I'll check it, I need to look at the certificate file in server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the APNs Production iOS type certificate on your production server.  If you use the certificate with the same name but with the type "APNs Development iOS" it will not send push notifications.

Comment: O.K know I'm working on production with "APN's Production iOS" but still don't get any notification, what strange is that the app that on app store also uses that prod certificate and works great. Maybe I cant test notification on production on my test devices without really publishing it on app store and downloading it from the store?